# Enter Layer URL not working in Esri Web Scene (AGOL)

Tags: wms, arcgis-online, web-scene

I'm trying to insert a WMS layer into my Web Scene in URL format.

[image]

This is the layer (WMS) in particular:

https://www.gebco.net/data_and_products/gebco_web_services/web_map_service/mapserv?request=GetMap&service=WMS&BBOX=-180,-90,180,90&srs=EPSG:4326&format=image/jpeg&layers=gebco_latest&width=900&height=600&version=1.1.1

Web Scene raises a yellow triangle once I paste the above URL in the first box, it seems to me that it doesn't like the format.

[image]

The URL however works fine in QGIS, but not in ArcGIS Online Web Scene Viewer, any ideas?

Comment: what exactly are you entering in each box?

Comment: the URL, and below just a name

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Online or something else?

Comment: This is the webscene viewer within an arcgisonline account

Comment: What if you use `https://www.gebco.net/data_and_products/gebco_web_services/web_map_service/mapserv?` for the layer URL and `gebco_latest` for the layer

Comment: That doesn't work either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add a WMS layer into Scene Viewer first add the WMS layer as an Item under My Content > Add Item > From the Web

Then Add the WMS layer item either through the item> open in Scene Viewer or in Scene Viewer Add Layer > My Content

WMTS requires the same workflow and can be added through the item but currently not from the URL. From URL supports adding ArcGIS Server Services like Map Services, Feature Services and Scene Services.

[image]